# Subscription breaks after Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

This problems occurs in Xamarin.Forms v.5.0.0.229 with FirebaseDatabase.net v.4.0.7. I haven't tried it with any other versions.

I have the following subscription:

```
firebaseClient.Child("Products")
     .AsObservable<Prod>()
     .Where(item => (item.Object.uid == _thisUid)
     .Subscribe(obs => {
         switch(obs.EventType) {
            case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate:
                var m = obs.Object;
                prodlist.Add(new Prod() {
                       Name = m.uniquename,
                    });
                }
            break;
            case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete:
                var m2 = obs.Object;
                foreach (var p in prodlist) {
                    if(p.uniquename== m2.uniquename) 
                        prodlist.Remove(t);
                } 
            break;
         }
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(prodlist)));
    }
```

Any number of actions of type Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate work fine until the first action Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete. After the latter gets processed, no subsequent subscription events get fired.

Comment: Are there any error message ？

Comment: Nope.  I tried catching onError, but it never breaks there.  It just hoses any further subscription notificationss until the page is closed (which I expect disposes of the subscription).